# PostGIS: Speed up intersect by filtering first

Tags: postgis, spatial-index, st-intersects, tile-server

I have a table with 20 million polygons where queries take some time (with an gist index on the geometries). I thought I could speed up the queries by first filtering on an additional id (selectivity: 1/600).

But the queries take basically the same time despite also creating an additional btree_gist index on `(id, geometry)`. The problem is that PostgreSQL runs my filter query and the intersect parallel instead of using the filter query first (Maybe it doesn't make sense? Is a selectivity of 1/600 too small? Does my `(id, geometry)`-index not work?)

Original query to calculate vector tiles:

```
WITH bounds as (...),
mvtgeom AS (
    SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(t.geom, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom,                                                                                                                                                
    FROM data t, bounds                                                                                                                                   
    WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 32632)))                                                                                                                                                            
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom;
```

Query with filter:

```
WITH bounds as (...),
WITH filter as (SELECT id FROM ... (WHERE x < n OR x > m) AND (y > n OR y < m)),
mvtgeom AS (
    SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(table.geom, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom,                                                                                                                                                
    FROM table, bounds, filter                                                                                                                                   
    WHERE ST_Intersects(table.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 32632)))
    AND table.id = filter.id                                                                                                                                                        
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom;
```

Comment: First of all, this is already what a GIST index does, check for bounding box intersection, before doing a proper intersection and second the ST_Transform in the WHERE clause means that your spatial index won't get used anyway, because it is now non sargable. Do, the transformation first, in a CTE, and then intersect on that later. Also, you should post the output of EXPLAIN, there will be some clues in there as to why your query is slow.

Comment: SImply pre-filtering indexed data generally defeats the purpose of the index, and with your idea here in particular. I disagree with @JohnPowell (nice to see you around again, though ;) ), the `ST_Transform` should not render the query sarg*un*able (or 'some time' would be 'some days'), but definitely have it transformed outside of the `JOIN` expression! Polygon intersections are costly; they get exponentially more expensive with the amount of vertices involved (in both comparing geometries: ~ `(vtc_g1 + vtc_g2)²`). Please post the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output as requested.

Comment: What are those bounds, bboxes or more complex areas? Are they static (i.e. somehow pre-defined) or dynamic (e.g. user-drawn)? How many vertices are we talking about in both geometries on average?

Comment: @geozelot, thanks, been a busy year. Sounds like you've got this covered :-)